# Separate Kubernetes ConfigMap data fields into individual files

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I'm playing around with kubernetes ConfigMaps. In the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#configmaps-and-pods), I see "file-like keys" in the `data` field:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: game-demo
data:
  # file-like keys
  game.properties: |
    enemy.types=aliens,monsters
    player.maximum-lives=5    
  user-interface.properties: |
    color.good=purple
    color.bad=yellow
    allow.textmode=true
```

Is it possible to break these "file-like keys" into different files and reference them in this ConfigMap resource?

I see several benefits of this approach:

- Slimmed down ConfigMap
- Proper syntax highlighting for the "file-like" configurations
- Can run auto formatters against the "file-like" configurations

Comment: no way to achieve this with bare kubernetes manifests: it is doable using either Helm or Kustomize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Proper syntax highlighting for the "file-like" configurations
> - Can run auto formatters against the "file-like" configurations

Yes, it is easier to save the files as proper files on your machine and in Git.

I propose that you use the [kustomize feature of kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) and use [configMapGenerator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#configmapgenerator) to generate the ConfigMap instead.

Example `kustomization.yaml` (saved in the same directory as your files, e.g. in `config/`)

```
configMapGenerator:
- name: game-demo
  files:
  - game.properties
  - user-interface.properties
```

Then you can apply (and generate the configMap) with (if your config is in `config/`):

```
kubectl -k config/
```

Or you can preview the "generated" configMap with:

```
kubectl kustomize config/
```